# How to prevent merge from falling back to normal merge strategy when a fast-forward merge is not possible?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

The `git merge` command has an option to perform fast-forward merge, but this is not what I want, because if it can't do a fast-forward merge, it uses the normal merge.

Is there a git command which **only** performs a fast-forward merge (from the tracked remote branch) and does nothing if the fast-forward merge is not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`git-merge`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) man page:

> --ff-only
>
> Refuse to merge and exit with a non-zero status unless the current HEAD is already up-to-date or the merge can be resolved as a fast-forward.

Comment: I could swear, this option was not yet available when reading the merge-documentation the last time. ;)

Comment: maybe someone merged it in since then :-)